# LatexIt alternative for Windows

Tags: windows, macos, latex, software-rec

I use a program in MacOS called latexit to create small pdf files of math text, that I can then put on presentations or open in Illustrator to modify. Is there a program that does this for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

There's a great thread over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270121/best-latex-editor-for-windows) with tons of Windows LaTeX editors.

Comment: Said "great thread" has been deleted.  :(

Answer (score 1):

There are three alternatives to LaTexIt that I've found:

1. [Laeqed](http://www.thrysoee.dk/laeqed/) - works well, no drag and drop, though
2. [KLatexFormula](http://klatexformula.sourceforge.net/download/) - has drag and drop, but tiny GUI text
3. [LatexEqEdit](http://latexeqedit.sourceforge.net/index.php) - have not tried